# Visual Studio Code expand selection to line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In sublime, you can select all text, and then hit `Expand selection to line` and a cursor will be placed on each line within the selection.

Is there an equivalent for VS Code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is called: `Create multiple cursor from selected lines`

- Select lines
- Press F1
- Type `multi`

Or press <kbd>Shift+Alt+I</kbd>

Note: Cursors will be at end of lines. Press <kbd>Home</kbd> to send them at beginning of lines.

Comment: Is there a way to specify if the cursor should be placed at beginning or end of the lines selected?

Comment: Afaik, there isn't. You can press `Home`

Comment: So what you are saying, there is a way on PCs. `Shift-Alt-I` then `Home`, and whatever is equivalent on your Mac. I'd add that Home comment to the answer, I think it adds value.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for thank! And the `Home` was helpful too.